# using history.js with IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, pushstate, history.js

In one of my applications i use `window.history.pushState()` method to update the window URL. But as `IE < 10` does not support HTML5's history api, I was looking for an alternative. Answers to a lot of other questions on SO suggested to use [`history.js`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) plugin.

From the documentation provided by the history.js plugin it's usage is not really clear. I have added the plugin to the `<head></head>` section in my templates but on IE9 i am still receiving the error that says:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'pushState'
params.js, line 37 character 5
```

the function that errors out is as follows

```
/**
 * updates the window url according to the given parameters.
 */
function updateUrl(params) {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var url = $.param.querystring(path, params);
    url = decodeURIComponent(new_url).replace("#", "", "g");
    window.history.pushState(null, null, new_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiatialize the History and State variables for it to work.

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    // Define variables
    var History = window.History,
        State = History.getState();

    // Bind statechange event
    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
        var State = History.getState();
    });
})(window)
```

and now you can use `pushState` method for all browsers as follows:

```
History.pushState(null, null, '?your=hash')
```

Comment: You were using 'window.history' instead of 'window.History' in conjunction with history.js.  Had nothing to do with initialization=)