# How do I get IE9 to work with historyapi in this symfony app using history.js, modernizr and or shim?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, backwards-compatibility, history.js

I have an app here, symfony2 based, and I include a shim and modernizr both, as well as a history.js.

My app runs fine in FF, but when I run it in IE, it complains about pushState method.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'pushState' 
>   2109519_appHistory_9.js, line 114 character 9

Here is kind of an example of what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";  //makes this entire object strict
    app.hist.init();  //init any code on this page
});

//Self-Executing Anonymous Function (Public & Private)
(function (hist, $, undefined) {

    app.hist.init = function () {

        if(history){
            console.log('we have history');
            console.log(history);
        } else  if(Modernizr.history){
            console.log('Modernizr.history');
            console.log(Modernizr.history);
        } else {
            console.log('no modernizr history');
        }

        app.hist.title = document.title;
        app.hist.url = document.URL;

        window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) { // or jquery $(window).on("popstate", function (e) {
            app.hist.popState(e);
        });
    };

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    app.hist.bindHistory = function(){

        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate

            app.hist.state = History.getState();
        });
    };

    app.hist.add = function () {

        app.hist.title = document.title;
        history.pushState( app.hist.state, app.hist.title, app.hist.url);  
    };

}(window.app.hist = window.app.hist || {}, jQuery));
```

console.logs yield this

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected  0438675_head_1.js, line 1 character 3164

LOG: we have history  

LOG: [object History]  

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'pushState'  2109519_appHistory_9.js, line 114 character 9
```

Notice, I put a bind method in there. I found that here:   [using history.js with IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634513/using-history-js-with-ie9)
This is where I think I need the help because that post wasn't enough info for me to figure out how to bind correctly to 'everything' needed so this will work in full, not just he state for e.g., but the title, and url, I don't even know how to get title and url using `History`, I don't see any methods for that, I only see `History.getState()`, I think there should be a `History.getTitle()` somewhere  https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#exposed-api, too, shoudln't there be?

1) Do I need to bind the historyjs like this to IE or something?

2) See that bind method, and tell me if I should be using it in init like I suspect

3) Please help me figure out what I need inside that bind method to get this bound properly.

**EDIT**:
OK, I see one problem, the `History.getState()`, but its an obj with all 3, state, title, url, WTF?  OK, so I have access to my stuff here then..

So I guess bindHIstory would look more like this then?
    app.hist.bindHistory = function(){

```
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate

        var data = History.getState();
        app.hist.state = data.state;
        app.hist.title = data.title;
        app.hist.state = data.url;
    });
};
```

So, still, same 3 questions above please.

Comment: oh wow, is this that difficult to solve that its generating yet a single comment?  hmm.  to bad it needs to be done last month, lol.

Comment: does anybody have any comments on this?  im legitimately stuck on this.